# Using inline css with DomPDF and Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, dompdf

I am having a problem with my inline css. So, I am trying to add a border under the data rendered from the database. The problem is the rendered data is under the name, the  How can I move the border-bottom and the rendered data at the right of the word "Name"?

here's the html code

```
<table style="border:none;border-collapse: collapse;font-size:12px;text-align: left;">
<tr>
    <td colspan="3"><b>I.  PERSONAL AND FAMILY DATA</b></td><td colspan="2"><b>Date today</b> <u>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($infomodel->date_last_updated)->format('m-d-Y') }}</u></td>
</tr>
<tr >
    <td colspan="3"><b>Name </b><div style="border-bottom:.7px solid black;height:15px;padding:0px;width:290px;overflow:hidden;">{!! $usermodel->last_name !!}, {!! $usermodel->first_name!!} {!! $usermodel->middle_name !!}.
      </div>
      </td>
    <td colspan="2"><b>Sex </b><u>{!! $infomodel->gender !!}</u></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="5"><b>Home Address </b><div  style="border-bottom:.7px solid black;height:15px;padding:0px;width:450px;overflow:hidden;">{!! $infomodel->mailing_address !!}
        
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table><br />
```

Here is the pdf view

[image]

Comment: you mean inline?

Comment: yes, i edited the code to its original format, please see the attached picture for reference. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Print the output in the styled element. And make the element to an inline element.

**Example:**
Change this :

```html
<td colspan="3"><b>Name </b><div style="border-bottom:.7px solid black;height:15px;padding:0px;width:290px;overflow:hidden;">{!! $usermodel->last_name !!}, {!! $usermodel->first_name!!} {!! $usermodel->middle_name !!}.
      </div>
      </td>
```

to this:

```html
<td colspan="3"><b>Name </b>
    <div style="display: inline; border-bottom:.7px solid black;height:15px;padding:0px;width:290px;overflow:hidden;">{!! $usermodel->last_name !!}, {!! $usermodel->first_name!!} {!! $usermodel->middle_name !!}.
    </div>
</td>
```

```html
<table style="border:none;border-collapse: collapse;font-size:12px;text-align: left;">
<tr>
    <td colspan="3"><b>I.  PERSONAL AND FAMILY DATA</b></td><td colspan="2"><b>Date today</b> <u>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($infomodel->date_last_updated)->format('m-d-Y') }}</u></td>
</tr>
<tr >
    <td colspan="3"><b>Name </b><div style="display: inline; border-bottom:.7px solid black;height:10px;padding:0px;width:290px;overflow:hidden;">
    {!! $usermodel->last_name !!}, {!! $usermodel->first_name!!} {!! $usermodel->middle_name !!}.
      </div>
      </td>
    <td colspan="2"><b>Sex </b><u>{!! $infomodel->gender !!}</u></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="5"><b>Home Address </b>{!! $infomodel->mailing_address !!}
        <div  style="border-bottom:.7px solid black;height:15px;padding:0px;width:450px;overflow:hidden;">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table><br />
```

Comment: i really need to use div because i need the border to show, since theres a lot of data with blank spaces im working with, it is really necessary to display the border-bottom

Comment: @CaptainCRAZY No proble. Then you add to the div style this css property: `display: inline;` . I updated my code in my answer.

Comment: @CaptainCRAZY You welcome! If it works, would be nice that you can accept this answer. Thank you!